# Der Begriff »Ziffer« in § 57 (4) der Rechtschreibregeln

Tags: spelling, numbers

§ 57 (4) der Rechtschreibregeln lautet:

> [Großgeschrieben werden:] Substantivierte Grundzahlen als Bezeichnung von Ziffern, zum Beispiel:
>   *Er setzte alles auf die Vier. Sie fürchtete sich vor der Dreizehn. Der
>   Zeiger nähert sich der Elf. Sie hat lauter Einsen im Zeugnis. Er würfelt
>   eine Sechs.*

Nach meinem Verständnis des Wortes (und auch z. B. demjenigen des [Dudens](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ziffer) oder der [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziffer)) bezeichnet das Wort *Ziffer* einzelne schriftliche Zeichen, also in unserem Zahlensystem die Ziffern Null bis Neun oder im römischen Zahlensystem I, V, X, L, C, D und M.

Nun bezieht sich keines der Beispiele auf Ziffern und die meisten noch nicht mal auf Zahlendarstellungen:

- *Er setzte alles auf die Vier.* – Man kann z. B. im Roulette alles auf die 23 setzen und mir wäre kein Beispiel bekannt, in dem diese nur durch eine einzige Ziffer repräsentiert ist. Ob sich dies auf die Zahldarstellung handelt, ist vermutlich schwer zu entscheiden.
- *Sie fürchtete sich vor der Dreizehn.* – Eine Ziffer Dreizehn gibt es in unserem Zahlsystem nicht. Auch beschränkt sich [Triskaidekaphobie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triskaidekaphobie) nicht auf die Zahldarstellung, sondern würde z. B. auch von einer Zusammenkunft von 13 Personen ausgelöst werden.
- *Der Zeiger nähert sich der Elf.* – Es gibt keine Ziffer Elf. Eine Zahldarstellung ist es aber.
- *Sie hat lauter Einsen im Zeugnis.* – Bezieht sich nicht auf die Ziffer, sondern auf die Zahl selbst. In einem anderen Notensystem könnte man sagen: »Sie hatte eine 15 in Mathe.«
- *Er würfelt eine Sechs.* – Auf den meisten Würfeln sind die Zahlen gar nicht durch klassische Ziffern repräsentiert. Außerdem scheitert dies bei Würfeln mit einer zweistelligen Seitenzahl. Schließlich ist dies nicht bloß eine Zahldarstellung, da der Zahlenwert in der Regel eine direkte Bedeutung hat.

Nun also zu meiner Frage:
Gibt es irgendein einigermaßen sinnvolles Verständnis des Begriffs *Ziffer* das all diese Beispiel erfasst? Oder etwas weiter gefasst: Wodurch müsste ich *Ziffer* ersetzen, damit die Beispiele zur Regel passen (Zahldarstellung habe ich bereits oben ausgeschlossen)?

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese Frage! Ich musste herzlich lachen aufgrund dieser mir vorher unbekannten, aber offensichtlich amüsanten Rechtschreibregeln. Erinnerte mich an Gottlob Freges "Über die Zahlen des Herrn Schubert", in der sich der Logiker Frege über die naive Erklärung des Zahlenbegriffs durch einen Herrn Schubert auslässt. Es beginnt mit den Worten: "In der Enzyklopädie [...] erklärt Herr H. Schubert die Zahl als Ergebnis des Zählens. In der Tat! ist nicht auch das Gewicht eines Körpers das Ergebnis des Wägens?"

Answer (score 1):

Du hast Recht, dass da ganz großer Humbug steht. Zur Verwechslung von Ziffer und Ziffernfolge kommt anscheinend auch noch das unberechtigte Bedürfnis hinzu, zwischen der Ziffern- und Wortrepräsentation von Zahlen zu unterscheiden.

Die einfachste Korrektur wäre also statt `Ziffer` das Wort

> Ziffernfolge

Wenn man mutig ist, wählt man stattdessen das Wort

> Zahl.

Man sollte sich aber vorher überlegen, was mit Ziffernfolgen ist, die keine Zahlen sind, z.B. 08/15.

> Der Kinofilm war echt Null-Acht-Fünfzehn.

Comment: *Ziffernfolge* entspricht grob meinen *Zahldarstellungen* aus der Fragestellung, deckt allerdings weder »Sie fürchtete sich vor der Dreizehn.« noch »Er würfelt eine Sechs.« ab (es sei denn, man wertet Würfelaugen als Ziffern). *Zahl* erfasst zwar alle obigen Beispiele (und beantwortet somit gewissermaßen meine Frage), aber leider auch ein paar kleingeschriebene Beispiele zu § 58 (6): »Er sollte die Summe durch acht teilen.«, »Dieser Kandidat konnte nicht bis drei zählen.«

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Du musst das "substantiviert" natürlich weiter beibehalten. Wobei ich auch nicht weiß was Grundzahlen sind.

Comment: @userunknown: Sind die Beispiele denn nicht substantiviert? Und kann man überhaupt eine klare Grenze zwischen substantivierten und nicht-substantivierten Zahlen ziehen? § 58 stellt ja selbst fest: »In folgenden Fällen schreibt man Adjektive, Partizipien und Pronomen klein, obwohl sie **formale Merkmale der Substantivierung** aufweisen.«

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Der Unterschied liegt nicht in „Substantivierung“ sondern in „Bezeichnung“. Großgeschrieben werden die Ziffernfolgen, die eben keine grammatikalischen Numerale sondern Bezeichnungen mathematischer Objekte sind. Beispiel: `Eine Telefonnummer besteht aus elf Ziffern.` Hier ist `elf` ein Numeral, d.h. es gibt direkt die Mächtigkeit der Betroffenen Menge an. `Die Telefonnummer endet auf eine Neun.` Hier ist `Neun` kein Numeral. Es gibt um keine Menge, sondern um das mathematische Objekt `9`, dessen Wortbezeichnung verwendet wird.

Comment: @Toscho: Aber was ist dann mit *drei* und *acht* in »Er sollte die Summe durch acht teilen.« bzw. »Dieser Kandidat konnte nicht bis drei zählen.«?

Comment: `durch acht teilen` wird klein geschrieben, weil der Hintergrund der Division eine Aufteilung auf acht gleiche Teile ist. Wenn man es nur als formale Rechenoperation `16:8` sieht, dann erkennt man das nicht. `bis drei zählen` ist unklar. Normalerweise wird Zählen mathematisch als bijektive Abbildung einer gegebenen Menge auf eine Teilmenge der natürlichen Zahlen definiert. Man kann es aber auch als Feststellung der Mächtigkeit der bisher gezählten Elemente der Menge definieren. Im ersten Fall sollte `Drei` groß geschrieben werden, im zweiten Fall `drei` klein.