# Warum schreiben wir "sprechen" mit 'e' und nicht mit 'ä'?

Tags: etymology, spelling

Wir schreiben "Sprache", davon das "Gespräch". Aber: wir "sprechen".

Woher kommt diese Ausnahme? Wieso schreiben wir nicht "sprächen".

Ich gebe hin und wieder Nachhilfe in Deutsch. Neulich hat mich mein "Schützling" genau das gefragt. Ich wusste keine Antwort.

Comment: Normalerweise was das Verb zuerst da

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Es handelt sich dabei nicht um eine Ausnahme, vielmehr sind die beiden Phänomene **Umlaut** und **Ablaut** voneinander zu unterscheiden.

**Ablaut** ist ein sehr altes Phänomen und wird schon seit indogermanischer Zeit benutzt, um Wörter und Wortformen voneinander abzuleiten. Das Standardbeispiel für den Ablaut ist die Konjugation starker Verben in Präsens, Präteritum und Perfekt:

> ich spr**e**che – ich spr**a**ch – ich habe gespr**o**chen

Heute nennen wir diese Verben unregelmäßig. Früher war diese Formenbildung aber recht regelmäßig, bloß haben zu viele Lautverschiebungen/Vokalveränderungen seit der indogermanischen Zeit stattgefunden, sodass wir die Regelmäßigkeit nicht mehr erkennen. [Früher hatte die erste Form ein *e* (Grundstufe), die zweite ein *o* (Abtönstufe) und die dritte gar keinen Vokal (Schwundstufe).]
Das Wort *Sprache* steht ebenfalls – wie die Vergangenheitsform *ich sprach* – in einem Ablautverhältnis zum Infinitiv *sprechen* (vgl. z. B. auch *geben – ich gab – die Gabe*).

Beim **Umlaut** handelt es sich um ein vergleichsweise junges Phänomen, das erst in althochdeutscher bis mittelhochdeutscher Zeit aufgetreten ist. Ursprünglich wurde der umgelautete Vokal an ein im Wort folgendes *i* angeglichen; beispielsweise ist ein *ö* einem *i* ähnlicher als ein *o* (um sich das einmal klar zu machen, kann man sich mit dem sogenannten [Vokaltrapez](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokaltrapez) beschäftigen). Später hat sich der Umlaut verselbstständigt und ist nicht mehr auf ein folgendes *i* angewiesen.

Wenn man *sprechen* mit *ä* schreiben möchte, würde man es also per **Umlaut** von *Sprache* ableiten. Dies würde die Etymologie aber umkehren, weil *Sprache* schon per **Ablaut** von *sprechen* abgeleitet ist.

Um die Sache noch zu verkomplizieren, gibt es ein paar Umlaute, die mit *e* statt *ä* geschrieben werden: *Eltern* enthält beispielsweise ein umgelautetes *a* (von *alt*); würde das Wort heute erst gebildet werden, würden wir es wohl *Älter(e)n* schreiben. Diesen Umlaut, der nicht mit *ä*, sondern mit *e* verschriftlicht wird, nennt man **Primärumlaut**; er trat bereits in althochdeutscher Zeit auf. *ä*, *ö* und *ü* als Umlaut von *a*, *o* und *u* entstanden dann später in mittelhochdeutscher Zeit.

Um dies alles auf einen Punkt zu bringen: Man kann nicht per se sagen, dass ein Wort mit *ä* geschrieben werden muss, wenn es eine verwandte Form mit *a* gibt. Denn eine Form mit *e* kann genauso gut mit der *a*-Form verwandt sein (entweder per Ablaut oder per Primärumlaut).

Answer (score 7):

Um das Ganze von einer anderen Perspektive aufzuziehen:

*Sprechen* wird [ʃpʀɛçn̩] gesprochen. Der Laut, um den es hier geht, ist also das kurze [ɛ].

- § 1 der [offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) ordnet diesen Laut dem Buchstaben *e* zu.
- § 13 besagt dann:

  > Für kurzes [ɛ] schreibt man *ä* statt *e,* wenn es eine Grundform mit *a* gibt.

  Zwar wird nicht genau definiert, was hier als Grundform angesehen wird, aber die Beispiele legen nahe, dass *Sprache* diese Funktion für *sprechen* erfüllt. Bis hierhin hat Dein Schützling also recht.
- Schließlich besagt § 15:

  > In einigen Wörtern schreibt man ausnahmsweise *e.*

  Bei diesen Ausnahmen von der Ausnahme bleibt einem nichts anderes übrig, als sie auswendig zu lernen. Sie sind in der Wortliste des Regelwerks angegeben, in der sich auch *sprechen* findet.

Die meisten dieser Ausnahmen sind historisch gewachsen (siehe auch [Chris’ Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/17547)), bei *sprechen* gäbe es aber noch einen weiteren Grund, es so zu belassen, und zwar die Vermeidung der Verwechslung mit der Konjunktivform *sprächen* (mit langem [ɛ]). Diese unterscheidet sich zwar durch die Länge aussprachetechnisch klar von *sprechen,* aber wir können diesen Unterschied nicht wie gewohnt orthografisch darstellen. Hierzu müssten wir nämlich im Indikativ das *ch* verdoppeln und *sprächchen* schreiben (vgl. auch die [Homogramme](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph) *[Hochzeit](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hochzeit_Feierlichkeit_Fest)* und *[Hochzeit](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hochzeit_Bluetezeit_Maximum)).
Sprechen* mit *e* zu schreiben ermöglicht uns hier, den Indikativ und den Konjunktiv II schriftlich zu unterscheiden.

Comment: Da nirgends definiert ist, wann eine Form eine "Grundform" ist, finde ich diese Duden-Regel relativ ungünstig formuliert. Sie führt überdies immer dann zu Unklarheiten, wenn ein *e* und ein *a* per Ablaut verwandt sind. Um zu wissen, was eine "Grundform" ist, braucht man etymologisches Grundwissen (z.B. muss man wissen, dass *Sprache* nicht die Grundform ist, sondern per Ablaut von *sprechen* abgeleitet ist.) Die Regel ist wirklich sehr unausgegoren (bloß meine Meinung).

Comment: Mit dem Duden hat dies alles nichts zu tun, der Duden hat seit 1996 nichts mehr Offizielles zu sagen (was meines Erachtens auch nicht zum Allerschlechtesten ist – diese Regeln sind meines Erachtens gegenüber den Duden-Regeln ein großer Fortschritt in Sachen Struktur und Übersichtlichkeit, aber [leider immer noch mit großen Mängeln](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/10963/2594)). Aber wir driften ab …

Comment: Du hast natürlich absolut Recht: Der Duden macht nicht die Regeln. Mein Fehler war, dass ich diese Regeln bei meiner Recherche selbst nachgelesen habe - und zwar im Duden. ;-)

Answer (score -4):

Man könnte sagen, wir sprechen ein e und kein ä, also ist es logisch auch e zu schreiben. So war es zumindest bis zu Rechtsschreibreform, bei der einige e-Schreibungen zu ä wurden. Ob das eine Vereinfachung oder Unsinn ist, sollte jeder für sich selbst beantworten.

"sprächen" ist außerdem die Konjunktivform zu "sprachen". Könnte sein, daß eine Schreibung mit ä zu Unklarheiten führen könnte.

Comment: Kurzes 'ä' (*Wände*) und kurzes 'e' (*wenden*) werden im Deutschen gleich ausgesprochen. Man kann sich also schon fragen, wann welcher Buchstabe geschrieben wird; die Aussprache ist kein ausreichender Hinweis auf die richtige Wahl.

Comment: Bei der neuen Schreibung aufwänden statt aufwenden denke  ich zuerst an die Wände hinauf.

Comment: aufwenden/aufwändig/aufwendig/Wand etc gehören zur selben Wurzel, die heute noch in 'winden' (sich drehen, wickeln) enthalten ist. 'wenden' ist das Kausativum zu 'winden' ('wenden'=ursprgl. 'jdn. dazu bringen, sich zu winden'). Eine Wand heißt so, weil sie früher aus Flechtwerk bestand ('Gewundenes'). Gehört alles zur gleichen etym. Wurzel. Teilweise ist nicht mehr nachzuvollziehen, welches Wort dieser Familie von welchem abgeleitet ist. Dementsprechend kann man nicht immer sagen, welcher Laut ein Ablaut ist ('e'-Schreibung) und welcher ein Umlaut ('ä'-Schreibung).

Comment: @Chris: dann warst du wohl noch nie im Schwabenland ;) Da ist ein "ä" ein "ä"...