# Datum und Uhrzeit groß schreiben?

Tags: spelling, time, capitalization, numbers, nominalization

Normalerweise schreibt man Daten und Zeiten mit Ziffern.

> - Am 5. Jan. um 9 Uhr.
> - Am 5. Januar um 9.00 Uhr.
> - Am 05.01. um 09:00.

Umgangssprachlich kann der Monat (wie das Jahr) und "Uhr" oft entfallen.

> - "Am 5. um 9."

Nach welcher Regel werden hier die Anfangsbuchstaben der Ordinalzahl und der Kardinalzahl gewählt?

> - Am fünften um neun.
> - Am **Fünften** um **Neun**.

Ich würde hier intuitiv Majuskeln wählen, aber in der Langform Minuskeln:

> - Am **fünften** Januar um **neun** Uhr.
> - Am Fünften Januar um Neun Uhr.

PS: Den Karnevalsbeginn am Martinstag, also dem 11. November, habe ich bisher fast immer groß gesehen: *am Elften im Elften, Elfter im Elften*. Ich erinnere mich hingegen nicht, die charakteristische Uhrzeit 11:11 je ausgeschrieben gelesen zu haben.

Comment: Bei der Uhrzeit bin ich bezüglich Großschreibung sehr skeptisch. Ist das wirklich etwas anderes als eine Entfernungs- oder Gewichtsangabe, wo man die Einheit weglässt? Gegenbeispiel in der Literatur: [Perutz, Zwischen neun und neun](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwischen_neun_und_neun)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Datum

Aus den offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln:

> **§ 57** Wörter anderer Wortarten schreibt man groß, wenn sie als Substantive gebraucht werden (= Substantivierungen).
>
> Substantivierte Wörter nehmen die Eigenschaften von Substantiven an
>   (vgl. § 55). Man erkennt sie im Text an zumindest einem der folgenden
>   Merkmale:
>
> a) an einem vorausgehenden Artikel *(der, die, das; ein, eine, ein),* Pronomen *(dieser, jener, welcher, mein, kein, etwas, nichts, alle, einige
>   ...)* oder unbestimmten Zahlwort *(ein paar, genug, viel, wenig ...),* die
>   sich auf das substantivierte Wort beziehen;
>
> b) an einem vorangestellten adjektivischen Attribut oder einem nach-
>   gestellten Attribut, das sich auf das substantivierte Wort bezieht;
>
> c) an ihrer Funktion als kasusbestimmtes Satzglied oder kasusbestimmtes Attribut.
>
> […]
>
> Ordnungszahladjektive sowie sinnverwandte Adjektive, zum Beispiel:
>
> Die Miete ist am Ersten jedes Monats zu bezahlen. […]

Bei *am Fünften* handelt es sich klar um eine substantivierte Ordnungszahl nach Merkmal a); der Artikel ist im *am* versteckt. Das zitierte Beispiel (am Ersten jedes Monats) ist zwar nicht identisch, kommt dem ziemlich nahe.

#### Zeit

> **§ 58** In folgenden Fällen schreibt man Adjektive, Partizipien und Pronomen klein, obwohl sie formale Merkmale der Substantivierung aufweisen.
>
> (6) Kardinalzahlen unter einer Million, zum Beispiel:
>
> *[…] Sie rief um fünf an. […]

Der Fall *um neun* ist also eine klar geregelte Ausnahme von der Großschreibung von Substantivierungen.

Comment: Also _am Fünften um neun_? Sind wir uns einig, dass das falsch wirkt?

Comment: Ja und ja. Die Regeln bezüglich der Großschreibung von Nummern sind m. E. kaputt (siehe auch [hier](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/10963/2594)).